# Can't use methods from RectTransformUtility

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wanted to use `RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle()` to implement a virtual trackbad on the touchscreen. 
So I typed `RectTransformUtility.` into my code and hit autocomplete. Nothing happens.
I wanted to be sure so I wrote the entire method call by hand `RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(socket.rectTransform, ped.position, ped.pressEventCamera, out position);` but now I get a compiler error. 
He does find `RectTransformUtility` tho, just not its methods. 
[Code and errors)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y81OK.jpg) (sorry that the error messages are in German)
I'm not 100% sure what socket and ped are but they should work since they are part of the code I got from uni as part of the exercise. 
Does anybody know what might cause this problem?

Comment: What does the compiler error say?  Are `ped.position` and `position` of type `Vector2`?

Comment: Where does your IDE leads you when you try to go to the definition of the `RectTransformUtility` class (F12 with Visual Studio)?

Comment: I already checked the definition for RectTransformUtility and all the Methods seem to be there. I'll upload an image of my errors. 1 sec.

Comment: You have to call `RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle` **inside** a function, otherwise, it does not make sense.

Comment: Oh. Ok. I didn't know it made that much of a difference. Thanks for the tip.